# Text variables don't persist in multiple levels

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to show the player name and the team name in multiple levels. I've created a gameobject with a singleton that calls servidor to load this variables. It works in the first level but not in the others. The gameobject persists but doesn't save the PlayerName and TeamName. How can I get it?

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


public class GlobalControl2 : MonoBehaviour
{
private static GlobalControl2 instance = null;

private Text PlayerName;
private Text TeamName;

void Awake ()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    } 
    else
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

public void Start()
{

    PlayerName = GameObject.Find ("PlayerName").GetComponent<Text> ();
    TeamName = GameObject.Find ("TeamName").GetComponent<Text> ();

    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.AccountDetailsRequest ()
        .SetDurable(true)
        .Send ((response) => {
            PlayerName.text = response.DisplayName;
        }  );

    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.GetMyTeamsRequest()
        .SetDurable(true)
        .Send(teamResp => {
            if(!teamResp.HasErrors)
            {
                foreach(var teams in teamResp.Teams)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Equipo: " + teams.TeamId);
                    TeamName.text = teams.TeamId;

                }

            }
        }  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are trying to persist Scene specific objects over multiple scenes

The data type "Text" is a unity object.

Try using "String" instead, in the example bellow you will see that **PersistentPlayerName** and **PersistentTeamName** will be available in the next scene and **PlayerName** and **TeamName** will not. This is always the risk that multi-scene singletons have.

Please do take note, that this should not required if PlayerName and TeamName is on the same gameobject as GlobalControl2  (the one you call DontDestroyOnLoad on)

I am not suggesting that you do it exactly as it is typed bellow, but this should be enough to set you on the right path, if not, add a comment and i will explain further.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;


public class GlobalControl2 : MonoBehaviour
{
private static GlobalControl2 instance = null;

private string PersistentPlayerName;
private string PersistentTeamName;

private Text PlayerName;
private Text TeamName;

void Awake ()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    } 
    else
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}

public void Start()
{

    PlayerName = GameObject.Find ("PlayerName").GetComponent<Text> ();
    TeamName = GameObject.Find ("TeamName").GetComponent<Text> ();

    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.AccountDetailsRequest ()
        .SetDurable(true)
        .Send ((response) => {
            PlayerName.text = PersistentPlayerName = response.DisplayName;
        }  );

    new GameSparks.Api.Requests.GetMyTeamsRequest()
        .SetDurable(true)
        .Send(teamResp => {
            if(!teamResp.HasErrors)
            {
                foreach(var teams in teamResp.Teams)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Equipo: " + teams.TeamId);
                    TeamName.text = PersistentTeamName = teams.TeamId;

                }

            }
        }  );
}
}
```

Comment: Yeeeees!! It works!! Thank you so much. And how can I do if I don´t want to shows it in all the screens? How can I exclude several scenes?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not how statics work, a static class will always be present once it has been initialized, unless you set it to null yourself, this is just how C# works and has nothing to do with Unity perse. (If the answer above helped you, please mark it as the answer)